# Telegram Bot API возвращает CHAT_ADMIN_REQUIRED, хотя бот имеет все права

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Я пишу telegram-бота (библиотека tgbot-cpp), и при вызове promoteChatMember я получаю исключение `Bad Request: CHAT_ADMIN_REQUIRED`, хотя бот имеет все права так и в группе, так и в настройках через BotFather: [image]

[image]

Я отправлял такой запрос через https, не используя никаких библиотек, но проблема та же. Что могло пойти не так?

Вот сам код:

```
static void revokeAdmin(BotInfo& botInfo, const TgBot::Message::Ptr& message)
{
  // spdlog::debug("Promoting admin...");
  // Я являюсь владельцем группы, поэтому необязательно меня продвигать.
  // botInfo.bot.getApi().promoteChatMember(message->chat->id, message->from->id, true);

  botInfo.bot.getApi().promoteChatMember(message->chat->id,
      message->replyToMessage->from->id);
}
```

(`botInfo` содержит самого бота и прочую информацию о нём, все параметры передаются правильно. Его поле bot имеет тип `TgBot::Bot`).

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Я изменил вопрос, добавил код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ прост: бот **не** может повышать/понижать администраторов, создателей.